# how can i update recyclerview inside fragment when click from another recyclview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I've a viewpager with two fragment in each one a RecyclerView one take the data from JSON and the other take it from sqlite DB there is a favorite button in the first recycler which inserts into DB but when swipe to next fragment it is not updated i want it to update in the same time

Comment: See [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use setUserVisiblityHint function for your second Fragmnet, it will call when fragment is visible every time , inside this you can update your adapter, 
when you swipe your fragment

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
                get your data from DB and notify adapter here
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In View Pager load the 2nd fragment view while first fragment loading. which is view pager default behavior.  so load the 2nd fragment values to recycler view value in setUserVisiblityHint.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(isVisibleToUser){
        // Load the value to recyclerview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only two fragments then the `OnCreateView()` will only get called once.

So you should add the code responsible for updating your `RecyclerView` in the `OnResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Update your RecyclerView from your database
}
```